# Creating and chmoding multiple directories with mkdir

Tags: php, function, mkdir, fine-uploader

I'm using `mkdir` function to create and chmod directories `$dirX` `$dirY`.

The following code block creates `$dirY` only and upload the desired file there. What's going wrong here? Why the other directory isn't being created along with the uploaded file?

```
$dirA = 'mydir1/';     
$dirB = '../mydir2/';   
$directory = array('$dirA','$dirB');
foreach ($directory as $dir); 


if (!is_dir($dir)){ 
mkdir($dir, 0777)
};


for($f=0; $f<count($_FILES['newsimage_upload']['name']); $f++) {
    $nume_f = $_FILES['newsimage_upload']['name'][$f];

   $thefile = $dir . '/'. $nume_f; //It doesn't set the directories of array's strings

 if (!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['newsimage_upload']['tmp_name'][$f], $thefile)) {
              $uploadresult[$f] = 'The file '. $nume_f. 'could not be copied, try again';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be something similar to:

```
$dirA = 'mydir1/';     
$dirB = '../mydir2/';   
$directory = array('$dirA','$dirB');
foreach ($directory as $dir){

if (!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0777);


for($f=0; $f<count($_FILES['newsimage_upload']['name']); $f++) {
    $nume_f = $_FILES['newsimage_upload']['name'][$f];

   $thefile = $dir . '/'. $nume_f; //It doesn't set the directories of array's strings

 if (!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['newsimage_upload']['tmp_name'][$f], $thefile)) {
              $uploadresult[$f] = 'The file '. $nume_f. 'could not be copied, try again';
}
//some more code
} //closing the for
//some more code
} //closing the foreach
```

Note that in your original code example there is a missing closing curly brace for the for loop, so I assume you closed it in your original code before the final foreach closing brace.

Comment: both sub-directories are created in the same directory. It seems that `$thefile = $dir . '/'. $nume_f;` can't recognize the path of `$dirB`. What's going wrong? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

`foreach ($directory as $dir);`

Make that

`foreach ($directory as $dir) {
...
}`

And you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`mkdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function has this functionality baked in already. Just specify the `recursive` option as `true`.

You also need to use [`realpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to resolve paths with dots in them.

Also, as stated by another answerer -- you need brackets around the inner-code block of your initial `foreach`.

```
$dirA = 'mydir1/';     
$dirB = '../mydir2/';   
$directory = array('$dirA','$dirB');
foreach ($directory as $dir){

// Note the next two lines which I have modified:
$realPath = realpath($dir);
if (!is_dir($realPath)) mkdir($realPath, 0777, $recursive=true);


for($f=0; $f<count($_FILES['newsimage_upload']['name']); $f++) {
    $nume_f = $_FILES['newsimage_upload']['name'][$f];

   $thefile = $dir . '/'. $nume_f; //It doesn't set the directories of array's strings

 if (!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['newsimage_upload']['tmp_name'][$f], $thefile)) {
              $uploadresult[$f] = 'The file '. $nume_f. 'could not be copied, try again';
}
//some more code
} //closing the for
//some more code
} //closing the foreach
```

Comment: I shall check the affect soon. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the return code from mkdir() should be checked to assure the directory was actually created.
the value of umask() may stop the created directory(s) from having the desired permissions,
so umask() should be saved/set to an appropriate value, then restored after the directory(s) are created.

There may be a problem with the line:
$directory = array('$dirA','$dirB');
as single quotes do not expand variables into their contents.
I suggest using double quotes on that line.

Comment: I shall observe the difference. Thanks,